# View State Problem

Tags: csv, viewstate

I am generating a csv file. For this i am using a visualforce page and its controller. I am able to generate csv. I am not able to see the view state of this page. Please tell me a way to view the view state of the page

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Apex & VF code snippets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see view state you need to enable View State in Development Mode for your user. For enabling View State in Development Mode follow the path given

Personal Setup -> My Personal Information -> Personal Information

Edit your personal information and check 'Show View State in Development Mode' checkbox is checked or not. If not then check it and save record.

Now go to your visualforce page and refresh it. You will find a new section appended at the bottom of the visualforce page. Now click on 'view state' on that section. Here you can find all view state related information such as which variables are used on page and which variable is of what size.